# How can I create a file with specific values using the dd command?

Tags: linux, dd

How can I create a file with specific number values using command dd in linux enviroment? I want a file size 4*500 (every integer number have 4 bytes and I want 500 positions).

My file want to have the format: `1234567890.....555`.

Comment: e.g. my file want to have the format:

1234567890.....555

Comment: peterh's answer is correct. You can only copy files or, more generally, streams of data with dd, typically from or to a block oriented device. That said, you are also unclear about the desired format. Is it binary (i.e. the bytes in your target file are 0x01, 0x02, 0x03... or is it a binary representation of 4 byte integers, like 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01 (first int), 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x02 (2nd int) etc.? (And then, which byte order?) Or is it an ascii representation, i.e. 0x31, 0x32, 0x33... (i.e. '1', '2', '3')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only with `dd` you can't do this. `dd` only copies a byte stream from its input to its output, it can't generate anything. You need to have same source for the `dd` which generates the needed data from.

The nearest which you can do that would be a simple shellscript, like this:

```
for i in $(seq 1 555);do echo -n $i;done
```

Of course, you can pipe its output into a `dd`as well, for example:

```
for i in $(seq 1 555);do echo -n $i;done|dd bs=4096 count=1
```